# Facebook Birthday field empty with GraphApi ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm running into a strange problem accessing to User birthday from my site.

The Facebook App is configured to have Birthday access:

[image]

From Server Side I get the Token using my AppId & AppSecret and then I call Facebook with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[USER ID]?fields=id,birthday,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=[MY TOKEN HERE]
```

As response I get all the Fields I'm interested in (email, first name, last name etc) except for BIRTHDAY.

In the App configuration the Birthday field is approved:

[image]

If I call it from the facebook console with the App Token:

[image]

Comment: why would you send the permission to review before making it work for your admin user? did you debug the user token to make sure the permission is authorized correctly?

Comment: Using the Graph Console, everything seems to work fine. From my App the field is always empty. The review is not sent yet!

Comment: you said it is "pending", so did you send it to review or not? you should not send anything to review if it does not even work in your app.  you need to have a working prototype.

Comment: Ok, I try to remove it and see what happens! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I successfully completed the Approval for Birthday field. Still is not working

Comment: does it work as app admin?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It works only with my personal user TOKEN, not with the App one!

Comment: of course it does not work with an app token, that would be weird...and why not just use /me instead of the user id? you need a user token with the user_birthday permission, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Facebook support, this is NOT working by design.

I was using the "App Token" to access to the personal information instead of the user token. Using the user token everything worked like a charm.

In few words: to access user info, use the user token.